# Controlling digits after decimal point in R summary

Tags: r, formatting, summary, significant-digits

Let the `data.frame` object `x` below

```
x <- data.frame(y = seq(0, 1, by = .1), 
                z = letters[1:11])
```

which can be summarized as follows:

```
> summary(x)                                                                                                 
       y              z    
 Min.   :0.00   a      :1  
 1st Qu.:0.25   b      :1  
 Median :0.50   c      :1  
 Mean   :0.50   d      :1  
 3rd Qu.:0.75   e      :1  
 Max.   :1.00   f      :1  
                (Other):5
```

**I would like to print the summary above with 6 digits after the decimal point**; the `summary` function has a `digits` argument, but running `summary(x, digits = 6)` gives the same output (two digits after the decimal point). It looks like that argument controls for *significant digits*, but the documentation and my own ignorance about the topic confused me to the point where I am not even sure that's what's happening.

I've tried playing around with `format` and `formatC`, but I can't find a way to produce the output I want, i.e.:

```
       y              z    
 Min.   :0.000000   a      :1  
 1st Qu.:0.250000   b      :1  
 Median :0.500000   c      :1  
 Mean   :0.500000   d      :1  
 3rd Qu.:0.750000   e      :1  
 Max.   :1.000000   f      :1  
                    (Other):5
```

Comment: well, looking at the `summary` function, the `digits`argument is called in `format()` which is restricted to show significant digits. You customize the function but it should be rather complex to show only trainling zeros for `y` yet not for `x`.